# Roots server do not update my new nameserver (CentOS bind DNS server)

Tags: domain-name-system, centos5, reverse-dns, dns-zone

Last week, I changed my dns nameserver from dns2.applistar.com to ns1.applistar.com.
But after that, my DNS server was downed. I do not know why :(.

I reconfig everything, but it still downed.

I used some dns checker website and found out that the roots server still kept my old nameserver and old IP (dns2.applistar.com).

what can I do that can make roots server update my new infomation?

My Named.conf

```
    options {
        directory "/etc/namedb";
        # Hung added for avoid cache poisoning
        #query-source address * port 53;
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;111.89.177.116;202.239.113.30; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
        allow-query     { any; };
        allow-transfer  { any; };
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        allow-query-cache { trusted; };

        recursion no;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        forwarders{202.239.113.30;8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;};
};
    controls{
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow {localhost;}
        keys{rndckey;};
};





acl "trusted" {
        202.239.113.30;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        127.0.0.1;
        localnets;
        66.27.53.114;
        65.24.0.172;
        24.30.200.19;
        24.30.201.19;
        204.62.114.188;
        204.62.114.179;
        208.67.222.222;
        208.67.220.220;
 };

zone "." in {
        type hint;
        file "named.root";
};

zone "applistar.com" in {
        type master;
        file "applistar.com.zone";
        allow-transfer {localhost;localnets;202.239.113.30/32; };
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "applistarproperty.com" in {
        type master;
        file "applistarproperty.com.zone";
        allow-transfer {localhost;localnets;202.239.113.30/32;        };
        allow-query {any;};
};

zone "116.177.89.111.in-addr.arpa" in {
        type master;
        file "177.89.111.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-query {any;};
         allow-transfer {localhost;localnets;202.239.113.30/32; };
};
```

My applistar.com.zone content:

```
    $TTL    86400
$ORIGIN applistar.com.
@       IN      SOA     ns1.applistar.com. root.applistar.com. (
                        2016022680
                        1D
                        3H
                        604800
                        1D )
        IN      NS      ns1.applistar.com.
        IN      NS      ns4.sphere.ad.jp.

;       IN      MX      1       ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
        IN      MX      10      mail.applistar.com.
        IN      MX      20      mail2.applistar.com.
*       IN      MX      10      mail.applistar.com.
ns1     IN      A       111.89.177.116
@       IN      A       203.138.124.133
www     IN      A       203.138.124.133
mail    IN      A       111.89.177.116
mail2   IN      A       111.89.177.116
www2    IN      A       203.138.124.133
www3    IN      A       203.138.124.133
mx2     IN      A       111.89.177.116
mx3     IN      A       203.138.124.133
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you ever changed the delegation for this zone.

Looking at the chain of delegations the parent zone refers to:

```
applistar.com.          172800  IN      NS      dns2.applistar.com.
applistar.com.          172800  IN      NS      mx2.applistar.com.
dns2.applistar.com.     172800  IN      A       211.19.48.186
mx2.applistar.com.      172800  IN      A       111.89.177.116
```

(See `dig +trace +add example.com NS` for reference.)

Change the delegation (through your registrar) to match whatever set of nameservers are desired (presumably `ns1.applistar.com.` + `ns4.sphere.ad.jp.`, from looking at the zone data included in the question?).

Also note that the *root* (`.`) nameservers are not the ones that need updated information but rather the `com` nameservers.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

So, how can I change the delegation? I have to asked my provider, haven't I?

Thank you.

Comment: @hugeitc You would do it through the registrar (as noted in the answer), normally they provide an interface where the customer can change the delegation.